# Read write privileges between Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, connection-string, ssms

I have a database I created from a back up. I am able to attach it to both Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and Visual Studio. The problem is when I attach it to with visual studio database is read only. The odd thing is I can edit the database in the Management studio.  Also, my project is not able to do anything but read as well. Only thing I can think of is VS and the aspx page are using different credentials than SSMS. I do not know how I can check that though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it on my own. The problem had to do with privileges. The database was on my local machine with limited rights. SSMS was using a different account to access the file than VS.I had to go to the MDF file and LDF and add rights to some users.